Search bar not working with image, with own API (HTML, JSON, JavaScript)
I am trying to create a search bar tool, a website, for guitar chords that let me search specific property codes: root and key. When I tried adding an image for each object the code messes it up and doesn't let me filter the root/key anymore whenever I search it up.
I am dying and I'm still new to JavaScript and I was hoping I could be guided in this issue. I am receiving the error:

Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: Cannot access 'isVisible' before initialization

What I want to happen with the image:

What happens when I put the image:

I am using Visual Studio Code, initialize npm as package and also using my own API.
npm init – y    

and
npm i json-server

When run into an error "not digitally signed", place in terminal:
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

npm start

and in package.json specify the path location of db.json
  "scripts": {
    "_comment": "Make sure to make the db.json file is the accurate/specific path",
    "start": "json-server --watch db.json"
  },

I have 4 main files (index.html, style.css, db.json, script.js) (two other files: package.json and package-lock.json)
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Guitar Chord Search</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="search-wrapper">
        <label for="search">Guitar Chord Finder</label>
        <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for chords" data-search>
    </div>

    <!--Where all guitar chord cards will go, each individual card-->
    <div class="user-cards" data-user-cards-container></div>
    <template data-user-template>
        <div class="card">
        <div class="header" data-header></div>
        <div class="body" data-body></div>
        <img class="img" data-image alt="Chord Image">
        </div>
    </template>
</body>
</html>

style.css
body {
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
}

.search-wrapper {
  margin: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .25rem;
}

input {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.user-cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  gap: .25rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.card > .header {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.card > .body {
  font-size: .8rem;
  color: #777;
}

/* Hide other cards during search */
.hide {
  display: none;
}

db.json
{
    "_comment": "Inside the object is the chord data (its the key), in the array put all the data of chord (array of objects)",
    "chord": [
        {
            "root": "A",
            "key": "Am",
            "picture": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/20594227/pexels-photo-20594227/free-photo-of-hands-of-man-playing-guitar.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "root": "A",
            "key": "Am7"
        },
        {
            "root": "A",
            "key": "A7"
        },
        {
            "root": "B",
            "key": "Bm"
        },
        {
            "root": "B",
            "key": "Bm7"
        },
        {
            "root": "B",
            "key": "B7"
        },
        {
            "root": "C",
            "key": "Cm"
        },
        {
            "root": "D",
            "key": "Dm"
        },
        {
            "root": "D",
            "key": "Dm7"
        },
        {
            "root": "E",
            "key": "Em"
        },
        {
            "root": "E",
            "key": "E7"
        },
        {
            "root": "F",
            "key": "F#m"
        },
        {
            "root": "G",
            "key": "Gmaj"
        }
    ]
}

script.js
const userCardTemplate = document.querySelector("[data-user-template]")
const userCardContainer = document.querySelector("[data-user-cards-container]")
const searchInput = document.querySelector("[data-search]")

let users = []

searchInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
  const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
  users.forEach(user => {
    const isVisible =
      user.root.toLowerCase().includes(value) ||
      user.key.toLowerCase().includes(value) ||
      //user.img.toLowerCase().includes(value)
    user.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible)
  })
})

fetch("http://localhost:3000/chord")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    users = data.map(user => {
      const card = userCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
      const header = card.querySelector("[data-header]")
      const body = card.querySelector("[data-body]")
      const img = card.querySelector("[data-image]")
      header.textContent = user.root
      body.textContent = user.key
      //img.src = user.picture

      if (user.picture) {
        img.src = user.picture;  // Set the src attribute if picture exists
      } else {
        img.style.display = "none";  // Hide the img element if no picture
      }

      userCardContainer.append(card)
      return { root: user.root, key: user.key, element: card }
    })
  })


//user.img.toLowerCase().includes(value) - by commenting out this line, you have concatenated the next expression to the previous conditions via that || operator on the previous line.

Works now thank you!

You should remove the last || operator
The below should resolve the uncaught error
const isVisible = user.root.toLowerCase().includes(value) || user.key.toLowerCase().includes(value) 
//user.img.toLowerCase().includes(value)
user.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible)


Thanks, removing the last | | operator works
